# Why did they need to say that the image is a subset?

Tags: ring-theory, terminology

I'm reading the course notes on rings at the moment, but noticed something that didn't quite make sense immediately to me.

> Suppose $R$ is a ring and $f : R \to S$ is a homomorphism. Let $T = \operatorname{im}f = \{f(a) \mid a \in R\}$ be a subset of $S$.

What I don't quite understand is, $S$ is the codomain of $R$ under $f$ since $f : R \to S$. So if we define $T$ to be the set of all $f(a)$ for any $a \in R$, then isn't $T$ exactly the same thing as $S$? Unless they are referring to the trivial subset (itself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with rings or ring homomorphisms.

Just to be clear, given a map $f : R \to S$, then $S$ is called the *codomain* of $f$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f) = \{f(r) \mid r \in R\}$ is called the *image* of $f$.

The codomain of a map and the image of a map are not the same in general, but the image is always contained in the codomain. They coincide if and only if the map is surjective (onto) - this is effectively the definition of surjectivity.

For example, consider the map $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$, $f(x) = x$. The codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, but the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z} \neq \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $f:R\to S$ refers that $S$ is a codomain of $f$, and this just means that the image of elements of $R$ under the map are contained in $S$, and it is not required that all the elements of $S$ are some image of $R$ by the map.